# SDL Tridion various questions- need help

Tags: 2013

SDL Tridion knowledge quiz- Need help or confirm answers for various questions.
1. If a author has parent structure group access, can he/she get same access level on child structure groups(y/n)? 
2. In VB which event triggering uploads .NET assembly to Content Management? A. Pre build event B. Post build event C. both A&B D. none 
3. Process definition can be associated with/to PageTemplate(true/false)? 
4. How many frameworks Tridion provide for ComponenTemplating? A.VB,JS templating framework B. Compound templating framework C. both A&B
5. When component is saved,which phase of Event handler can be used for overriding the content of a component? A. transaction commited B. initial C. processed. D. transction rolled back.
6. Template builder can be used to create following? A. Component template B. Page template C. TBB D. all of them.
7. Can structure group be member of another structure group(true/false)?
8. Is it possible to set breakpoint and debug c# DLL using VB(true/false)?
9. .Net dll used to create TBB's must implement interface? A. ITemplate B. ITCMEvents c. IFunctionsource D. Imediator E. No need to implement any interface
10. Reuability feature is limited in .Net templating? A. true B.false
11. Is below statements true? A. Events are organized in  hierarchy. B. By catching blueprint events both localize and unlocalize events are caught. C.By catching versioning events, save, delete and Rollback events can be captured. D.only A and B true.
12. Parameter schema used to  A. Add some metadata in Component/page B. Add some metadata in Component Template C. Pass parameter to TBB D. create component E. create TBB.
13. Will errors raised during phases after Content Management action cause the CM action to be rolled back(yes/No)? 
14. Can custom page be configured to available for specific user groups (yes/no)?
15. Can we cancel workflow instance in middle(yes/no)?
16. Different activity types available in workflow module?  A. Manual decision B. Manual activity C. Automatic decision activity. D. Automatic activity.
17. Dreamweaver template custom function can be used by? A. Adding custom function dll as a reference in c# template. B.Adding custom function TBB in compound template. C.Register it in GAC and update the tridion ContentManager.config with the path of newly created custom function dll. D. None . E.Directly add a call in dreamweaver template.
18. When more than 1 content manager running, is it enough to install event handler on only one content server?(yes/no)
19. If workflow associated to parent StructureGroup, Does it get inherited to child StructureGroups(yes/no)?
20. Can user act on multiple workflow instances in one go(yes/no)?
21. While using custom pages, user rights in application will not be applicable(true/false)?
22. Events can be subscribed based on?  A. subject type B. event type C. All D. phase 
23. To create keywords what rights user need to have to publication?......
24. Is it possible to create Component Template that can be used with components based on different schemas(yes/no)?
25. Can we disable user without deleting user(yes/no)?
26. Langauges used to create TBB? A. jscript. B. VB script C. C# fragment/dll D. XSLT. E. All
27. Where can we see all lists of active worflow instances?..... 
28. When component is saved for first time, tcm uri is available in initial phase(yes/no)?
29. After completing custom function for Dreamweaver template, we can use these functions by?......

Comment: Please stick to one question and make sure it fits within the parameters of what is a good fit for Tridion Stack Exchange (see http://meta.tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/370/how-to-ask-a-good-question-on-tridion-stack-exchange). This is not a place to just dump all of your questions and hope that people do your research for you :)

Comment: I'm missing q 30? WTF?!

Comment: I wonder if this is our new certification exam questions... :)

Comment: You mean "was" your new exam questions?

Comment: @robrtc, I think the rewrite makes for a somewhat better question but now the amount of down votes and comments don't match the original question.

Comment: Also, I don't want to imply the original questions are actually from the SDL Web Certification without confirmation. And honestly, I'm not inclined to double check right now. If they are SDL's or anyone's certification exam questions, this post can very well be grounds for automatic failure. I would like to give Subba the opportunity to better understand Tridion StackExchange and to ask better questions.

Comment: I removed *on hold* and locked this question. "On hold" implied this question could be improved but it's probably better to start new, separate questions.